# Kotlin: Unresolved reference: javaClass

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm hoping someone has come across the issues that i'm seeing while building my java/Kotlin project.
The project is interop with java and kotlin, with the following versions:

- Jdk 1.7
- Kotlin 0.9.66
- Gradle (wrapper) 2.0

Kotlin has been compiling fine prior to a few changes i made i.e.  converted a few java classes to equivalent kotlin versions.

Here are the errors that i'm seeing:

```
  c:\projects\myproject>gradlew  :java:workspace:models:compileKotlin  --stacktrace     :java:workspace:models:compileKotlin

w: Annotations path entry points to a non-existent location:
C:\projects\myproject\java\workspace\models\annotations

e: C:\projects\CustomerProfileEmail.kt: (15, 32): Unresolved reference: toLowerCase
e: C:\projects\CustomerProfilePhone.kt: (34, 22): Unresolved reference: equalsIgnoreCase
e: C:\projects\Account.kt: (17, 21): Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\Account.kt: (18, 21): Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\Account.kt: (31, 15): Unresolved reference: indexOf
e: C:\projects\Account.kt: (35, 15): Expression 'length' of type 'kotlin.Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function invoke() is not found
e: C:\projects\Account.kt: (39, 15): Expression 'length' of type 'kotlin.Int' cannot be invoked as a function. The function invoke() is not found
e: C:\projects\Balance.kt: (10, 21): Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\Balances.kt: (12, 21): Unresolved reference: firstOrNull
e: C:\projects\Balances.kt: (12, 35): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. To specify it explicitly use the {(p : Type) -> ...} notation
e: C:\projects\Debit.kt: (7, 12):Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\ProgramR.kt: (12, 21): Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\ProgramR.kt: (13, 21): Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\Transaction.kt: (7, 12): Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\Transaction.kt: (7, 40): Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\Adjustment.kt: (13,21): Unresolved reference: javaClass
e: C:\projects\Reward.kt: (12, 24): Unresolved reference: javaClass
:java:workspace:models:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Here is an example of the source code:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*

XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
XmlType
XmlSeeAlso(javaClass<LoyaltyCredit>(), javaClass<Debit>())
public open class Transaction: TransactionParent(){
    public var account: Account? = null
    public var balances: Balances? = null
    public var rewards: Rewards? = null
}
```

Gradle script

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.connorgarvey.gradle:gradle-grails-wrapper:1.0'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.9.66'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.9.66'
    }
}

apply from: 'build/includes.gradle'
```

I have already seen this: https://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5478050 didn't help.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you found a fix which you made, but is not mentioned direcltly in the accepted answer, please update your question with an edit that describes how you resolved the situation.  otherwise might find this question and have no idea what "the reference helped in looking in the right direction" actually means in identifying the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare your script with Kotlin [reference](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) about Gradle.

Kotlin Stdlib dependency should be in another scope, not `buildscript`.
Also Kotlin plugin should be applied using `apply plugin`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I am working with a very convoluted script.  So even though i had the same script as the one referenced, it was being overridden down the line of imported scripts.  The reference helped in looking in the right direction!

Comment: @WolfBane please update your question or add a comment here on the actual solution you found.